# Two tables sharing same dataset in report

Tags: postgresql, jasper-reports

I am using *iReport 4.0.2*. I have two tables in report sharing same dataset, so that some fields are in one table and rest are displayed in another table. But the it is executed first table is printed twice and second table is not displayed.
How I can solve this problem?

I am using *PostgreSQL*

My query I have used in dataset is

```sql
SELECT 
fst_insp_qpqlml."date_of_inspection" AS date_of_inspection,
fst_insp_qpqlml."land_type" AS land_type,
fst_insp_qpqlml."are_structures" AS are_structures,
fst_insp_qpqlml."is_contiguous" AS is_contiguous,
fst_insp_qpqlml."report_court_orders" AS report_court_orders,
fst_insp_qpqlml."has_crusher_attached" AS has_crusher_attached,
fst_insp_qpqlml."eou_ssi" AS eou_ssi,
fst_insp_qpqlml."cutting_unit_location" AS cutting_unit_location,
fst_insp_qpqlml."capacity_cubic_meter" AS capacity_cubic_meter,
fst_insp_qpqlml."capacity_square_meter" AS capacity_square_meter,
fst_insp_qpqlml."has_distinct_industrial" AS has_distinct_industrial,
fst_insp_qpqlml."has_distinct_industrial_programme" AS has_distinct_industrial_det,
fst_insp_qpqlml."is_harmful" AS is_harmful,
fst_insp_qpqlml."env_issue_accidents" AS env_issue_accidents,
fst_insp_qpqlml."mineral_supplied_to" AS mineral_supplied_to,
fst_insp_qpqlml."details_heavy_mechines" AS details_heavy_mechines,
fst_insp_qpqlml."quarrying_area" AS quarrying_area,
fst_insp_qpqlml."quantity" AS quantity,
fst_insp_qpqlml."total_reserve" AS total_reserve,
fst_insp_qpqlml."toposheet_no" AS toposheet_no,
fst_insp_qpqlml."details_magistrate_court" AS details_magistrate_court,
fst_insp_qpqlml."is_reserved" AS is_reserved,
fst_insp_qpqlml."land_assigned_special_purpose" AS land_assigned_special_purpose,
fst_insp_qpqlml."details_court_attatchment_nonliability" AS details_court_attatchment,
fst_insp_qpqlml."other_detail" AS other_detail,
fst_insp_qpqlml."is_special_permit" AS total_reserve 
FROM "public"."fst_insp_qpqlml" fst_insp_qpqlml 
WHERE fst_insp_qpqlml.application_id=$P{applicationId}
```

Comment: can you please show your data structure?
i.e table and data 
the problem is related to your sql query
also which database are you using.

Comment: i see that your query is using only one table.
use http://www.sqlfiddle.com/ to show your tables and data.
the actual output and desired output